# Date change on Specific time

Tags: php, datetime

```
//Daily Date Update 
$estTime = (new DateTime('America/New_York'))->format('H:i');
//echo $estTime;
if($estTime > "01:00"){
$mydate= date('n/j/Y');
}
else{
$mydate= date('n/j/Y',strtotime("-1 days"));
}
echo $mydate;
```

I want to get new date at midnight 1 am otherwise it will provide yesterday date. For example today 7/21/2017.
If date and time is 7/22/2017 00:59 result will be 7/21/2017
if date and time is 7/22/2017 01:00 result will be 7/22/2017

Comment: Till  date and time is 7/22/2017 00:59 result will be 7/21/2017 

Else  7/22/2017 01:00 result will be 7/22/2017 New Date 
@ravi

Comment: Got your question, then what your problem. Your existing code should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change date at exact 1'o clock. Then you should add an equal sign to your code.

> if($estTime >= "01:00")

```
//Daily Date Update 
$estTime = (new DateTime('America/New_York'))->format('H:i');
//echo $estTime;
if($estTime >= "01:00"){
$mydate= date('n/j/Y');
}
else{
$mydate= date('n/j/Y',strtotime("-1 days"));
}
echo $mydate;
```